# Using grunt + django, ways to speed up compiling some SASS? (3.3 and compass, with user themes)

Tags: django, performance, sass, gruntjs

#### THE PROBLEM

I'm looking for a way to decrease the 40-50 second wait every time our SASS needs to compile into main.css. I've already gotten it down from over a minute by switching from using Compass for compiling to using grunt-contrib-sass. I need to get it down to 5-10 seconds, or as close to that as possible.

#### CAN'T USE LIBSASS

I'm a little bit stuck using SASS 3.3 and Compass unless we absolutely have to switch for the performance. We do use bootstrap-sass so it would be hard to get rid of Compass entirely. This means we can't easily switch to libsass. But any code in Compass can also be copied from their repository directly into our _mixins partial so anything is possible with enough effort.

#### USER THEMES

The worst thing for our speed by far is that we have different usergroups, each with their own set of variables used to compile the SASS with a custom theme. So our SASS needs to compile once for the main theme, main.css, and then once more for each usergroup in the system to make their theme.css. As we add users the compile time that results when any of our main partials are changed increases linearly. Any suggestions to speed this up are also welcome.

#### REPLACE @IMPORT WITH REQUIRE?

I read on the TreeHouse blog that @import slows things down a lot when using the stock Ruby SASS compiler. We do have a lot of partials, and the user themes as well, and we have bootstrap-sass rigged to compile using our variables instead of bootstrap's default ones. So there are a lot of @import statements. TreeHouse used Sprockets in their Rails project, replacing @import with //=require, to speed up their ~1min SASS compilation to something like 3 seconds. Django has a port of Sprockets called django-gears, could implementing that have the same effect on our SASS? Can we use django-gears together with grunt? There doesn't seem to be much mention of using the technologies together in the Google-sphere.
(edit: found the article I was talking about, updated this section. http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/tale-front-end-sanity-beware-sass-import)

Edit 2: No, Grunt and django-gears don't really work together. I don't think we need to use Gears to achieve this effect though. I'm going to  try using some sort of Grunt file concatenation plugin to replace the Sass @import statements, I'll report back here about what it does to our compilation time.

#### CONCLUSION

Anyway, that's all the research I've done so far, pretty much. We could rewrite our SASS to work with libsass, which would be tough and take a decent amount of time. We can implement django-gears to possibly-maybe speed things up using require. Or, not mentioned yet, we can replace Grunt with Gulp. Gulp seems to have a slightly faster version of grunt-contrib-sass but might cause trouble if we need a plugin later down the line that doesn't exist for Gulp (since Gulp is smaller/not as well-supported as Grunt).

Is there anything that I've missed so far in my research? Any further suggestions? I'm not terribly experienced so any sage advice Stackoverflow has to offer would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Have you tried compiling with *just* Compass (or *just* Sass)?  No Django, no Grunt, etc.

Comment: Yes, we were originally just using compass watch/compile to compile the Sass. It took forever (>1 minute). Switched to grunt-contrib-sass (we already had grunt set up, but were using vanilla Compass to compile the sass) and our compile time improved to be under a minute. A decent improvement, but still not quite enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as an answer instead of an update to the question because we did find an acceptable solution to our speed problems. There's always room for improvement though (and our compilation time is still hovering at a bit above average). I ended up refactoring everything to work with grunt-sass and our total compile time, including all main and customer themes, dropped to ~5 seconds.

By the way, using grunt-concat or any other way to circumvent the Sass @import statement didn't speed things up at all. I'm not sure what crazy bug the TreeHouse Blog developers experienced that implementing Sprockets fixed, but what worked for them didn't work for me.

The real breakthrough came when I found the article [Is Libsass, the lightning fast Sass compiler, ready for prime time?](http://benfrain.com/libsass-lightning-fast-sass-compiler-ready-prime-time/), written by Ben Frain. He mentions a library called [sass-list-maps](https://github.com/lunelson/sass-list-maps), written by [Lu Nelson](https://github.com/lunelson), that emulates Sass 3.3 maps in lower versions of Sass. Using sass-list-maps and some of the other tips in that article, I refactored our Sass until it resembled a much earlier version. It didn't take a huge amount of time despite our large codebase, I just commented out all the partial imports in `partials/_all.scss` and added them back in one at a time, compiling with grunt-sass each time and fixing any errors (manually inspected the CSS too, there were some bugs there that didn't cause compilation errors).

The only thing left to work around was Compass, which wouldn't compile with libsass even after I copied it into our project from github. We ended up replacing Compass with [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/), a mixin library that will add itself to the file structure of your project so it is easily accessible to import. It also has the side-effect of being very lightweight and sharing most of the same syntax as Compass so almost no changes were in order there. It's fully compatible with libsass/node-sass.

In the end, our Sass compiles way faster, and everyone is happy. 5 seconds is still a little on the long side with grunt-watch running it's only a minor annoyance. If I manage to bring the compile time down more I'll post how I did it here as well.